# The method findViewById(View, int) is undefined for the type Contacts.Intents.UI

Tags: android

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View layout = convertView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.complex1, null);
            AphidLog.d("created new view from adapter: %d", position);
        }

        final Travels.Data data = travelData.get(position % travelData.size());

        UI.<TouchImageView> **findViewById**(layout, R.id.photo).setImageBitmap(
                IO.readBitmap(inflater.getContext().getAssets(),
                        data.imageFilename));

        return layout;
    }
```

Error in **findViewById**.
I don't know.Help me to solve.
There display :

The method `findViewById(View, int)` is undefined for the type `Contacts.Intents.UI`

Comment: are you using xamarian or so? but the error means that, the object does not have that funtion, if you want to use `findViewById` then you need to call it from a `View` object which is `layout` in your case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `finViewById()` use `layout.findViewById()` which will search for a `View` by its id on the `View layout`.

Comment: Can you add some explanation to your answer please?

Comment: Inside getView()  findViewById() should be used with reference of inflated layout reference .

Comment: Just Import import com.aphidmobile.utils.UI;